# Safely handling deeply nested and complex json object in Angular api service

Tags: angular, typescript, nested, rxjs

I'm developing an API service for a carwash that retrieves a large, complex json object (a Carwash object). Almost every property of this object is another object that contains a mix of simple data types and other custom objects **that must be instantiated**. I've seen plenty of examples for objects with 1 or 2 levels of properties that utilize the RxJs map function, but for deeply nested objects like this it does not seem feasible.

Carwash.model.ts overview

```
export class Carwash {
public name: string;
public type: CARWASH_TYPE;
public rating: Rating;
public address: Address;
private _coordinates: CarwashCoordinates;
public promotions: Promotion[];
public silverPackage: Package;
public goldPackage: Package;
public platinumPackage: Package;
public exteriorPackage: Package;
public interiorPackage: Package;
public completePackage: Package;
public storeHours: StoreHours;
}
```

ApiService.ts

```
public static carwashUrl = 'http://localhost:4200/assets/data/carwash.json';
private static carwashObject: Carwash;
public name: string;
public type: CARWASH_TYPE;
public ratings: Rating[];
public address: Address;
private _coordinates: CarwashCoordinates;
public promotions: Promotion[];
public silverPackage: Package;
public goldPackage: Package;
public platinumPackage: Package;
public exteriorPackage: Package;
public interiorPackage: Package;
public completePackage: Package;
public storeHours: StoreHours;
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
}

public getCarwash() {
    console.log('getCarwash called');
    if (!CarwashService.carwashObject) {
        this.fetchCarwash().subscribe(
            (carwash => CarwashService.carwashObject = carwash)
        );
    } else {
        console.log('Carwash already fetched.');
    }
}

private fetchCarwash(): Observable<Carwash> {
    return this.http.get<any>(CarwashService.carwashUrl).pipe(
        map(res => {
            const carwashData = res.json();
            this.name = carwashData.name; // Top level stuff is np
            this.type = carwashData.type; // Top level stuff is np
            for (const rating of carwashData.ratings) {
                this.ratings.push(new Rating(rating.customerName,
                    rating.score,
                    rating.review,
                    rating.date)); // Top level stuff is np
            }
            this.address = // When it comes to instantiating custom objects I'm not sure how to go about it in an elegant way.
            return new Carwash(this.name, this.type, etc...)
        })
    )
}
```

Is mapping the only way to achieve this? Should I implement helper functions to clean up the get call? I don't know.

NOTE: Custom object structure isn't necessary. All you need to know is that they are composed of basic data types as well as other custom objects.

Comment: Maybe **pluck** is a way to [go](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/pluck.html). Check this [article](https://medium.com/javascript-everyday/rxjs-map-vs-pluck-operators-9124942d610f).

Comment: Check out [lodash flatMap](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.14#flatMap), as well as flatMapDeep and flatMapDepth.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do the following:

```
http.get<CarWash>(this.carwashApiUrl).subscribe((carwash: CarWash) => console.log(carwash));
```

... of course your CarWash class needs to have all available complex properties defined. For this kind of definitions, you can also use generators like the Swagger Editor to get them out of your api's class definitions (if you have them).
Afterwards, you could still map your CarWashDto to a CarWash object however you need it in the UI.

Comment: I just tried this to confirm ... and it does automatically map all of your nested items appropriately. But note that they are all *shaped* like the defined types ... they are *not* actually instances of those types. If you need them to be instances (to call methods for example), then this technique isn't enough.

Comment: Sorry I updated my question to clarify. I'm aware of this technique but need each custom object to be instantiated as most of them contain their own functions.

Answer (score 1):

If you need actual object instances, not just an object graph shaped with the appropriate types, then you can use code something like this:

**Using Object.assign:**

```
  productsClassInstance$ = this.http.get<ProductClass>(this.productsUrl)
    .pipe(
      map(product => Object.assign(new ProductClass(), {
        ...product,
        suppliers: (product.suppliers ? product.suppliers.map(supplier => Object.assign(new SupplierClass(), {
          ...supplier
        })) : [])
      }))
    );
```

This uses the `map` operator to map the response to the object graph. It leverages `Object.assign` to create a new instance of the class and the spread operator (...) to copy the data into that new instance.

For each "child" object or array of objects, you can use similar code.

[Updated for multiple levels of objects]

**OR Using constructors**

```
productsClassInstanceMultipleLevels2$ = this.http.get<ProductClass[]>(this.productsUrl)
.pipe(
  map(products => products.map(product => 
    new ProductClass(
      product.id, 
      product.productName,
      (product.suppliers ? product.suppliers.map(supplier => new SupplierClass(
        supplier.id,
        supplier.name
      )) : []) ))
  )
);
```

[Updated again to use constructors instead of Object.assign]

Comment: fun fact I just heard you in AiA episode this morning on my way to work came home to see you in so. on topic +1.

Comment: Hmm, this is interesting. Have you tested this though? I implemented a similar solution and the Object.assign function won't work with a class that expects arguments...which is every class in my case.

Comment: I did. You can find it here:https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-RxJS/tree/master/APM-WithExtras in the product.service, property: productsClassInstanceMultipleLevels$. Notice that my class constructors have no parameters

Comment: At first glance, it looks like you'll either need to change the classes to define a parameterless constructor and use the spread syntax. Or use the constructor and manually specify every property.

Comment: Still not sure about it all. The constructor solution is essentially what I was trying to avoid. I did try it with Object.assign, but the code length/readability is essentially the same (spread operator doesn't benefit me much here). Also, is the Object.assign approach not hacky when trying to implement with a class? Suppose I need to use the class in a traditional way later using the constructor. There is no overloading in JS/TS so then...

Comment: What sort of solution were you hoping to find?